# Plot a stacked area in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, stack

I want a stacked area chart wherein x-axis I have the years and, on the y-axis, I have the number of occurrences of crises per year.
There are three different types of crises: 1. Banking, 2. Currency and 3. Sovereign debt.
My goal is to observe the co-occurrence of these 3 types of crises.

I first started by counting each crises dividing them by years, like this

```
panel_3%>%   #df1 is yor data frame
  filter(lv18_bank_c==1) %>%
  group_by(Year)%>%
  summarise(freq=n())


 panel_3%>%   #df1 is yor data frame
  filter(v18_cur_c == 1) %>%
  group_by(Year)%>%
  summarise(freq=n())


panel_3%>%   #df1 is yor data frame
  filter(lv18_sovdebt_c_def ==1) %>%
  group_by(Year)%>%
  summarise(freq=n())
```

However, I do not know how to construct the plot with this.

I already done this in excel but the resolution isn't good. Can you help me ?

The example of the plot in excel is below

[image]

The original data frame that I have is this

```
       Country Year lv18_bank_c lv18_cur_c lv18_sovdebt_c_def
1      Albania 1980           0          0                  0
2      Albania 1981           0          0                  0
3      Albania 1982           0          0                  0
4      Albania 1983           0          0                  0
5      Albania 1984           0          0                  0
6      Albania 1985           0          0                  0
7      Albania 1986           0          0                  0
8      Albania 1987           0          0                  0
9      Albania 1988           0          0                  0
10     Albania 1989           0          0                  0
11     Albania 1990           0          0                  1
12     Albania 1991           0          0                  0
13     Albania 1992           0          0                  0
14     Albania 1993           0          0                  0
15     Albania 1994           1          0                  0
16     Albania 1995           0          0                  0
17     Albania 1996           0          0                  0
18     Albania 1997           0          1                  0
19     Albania 1998           0          0                  0
20     Albania 1999           0          0                  0
21     Albania 2000           0          0                  0
22     Albania 2001           0          0                  0
23     Albania 2002           0          0                  0
24     Albania 2003           0          0                  0
25     Albania 2004           0          0                  0
26     Albania 2005           0          0                  0
27     Albania 2006           0          0                  0
28     Albania 2007           0          0                  0
29     Albania 2008           0          0                  0
30     Albania 2009           0          0                  0
31     Albania 2010           0          0                  0
32     Albania 2011           0          0                  0
33     Albania 2012           0          0                  0
34     Albania 2013           0          0                  0
35     Albania 2014           0          0                  0
36     Albania 2015           0          0                  0
37     Albania 2016           0          0                  0
38     Albania 2017           0          0                  0
39     Albania 2018           0          0                  0
40     Albania 2019           0          0                  0
41     Algeria 1980           0          0                  0
42     Algeria 1981           0          0                  0
43     Algeria 1982           0          0                  0
44     Algeria 1983           0          0                  0
45     Algeria 1984           0          0                  0
46     Algeria 1985           0          0                  0
47     Algeria 1986           0          0                  0
48     Algeria 1987           0          0                  0
49     Algeria 1988           0          1                  0
50     Algeria 1989           0          0                  0
51     Algeria 1990           1          0                  0
52     Algeria 1991           0          0                  0
53     Algeria 1992           0          0                  0
54     Algeria 1993           0          0                  0
55     Algeria 1994           0          1                  0
56     Algeria 1995           0          0                  0
57     Algeria 1996           0          0                  0
58     Algeria 1997           0          0                  0
59     Algeria 1998           0          0                  0
60     Algeria 1999           0          0                  0
61     Algeria 2000           0          0                  0
62     Algeria 2001           0          0                  0
63     Algeria 2002           0          0                  0
64     Algeria 2003           0          0                  0
65     Algeria 2004           0          0                  0
66     Algeria 2005           0          0                  0
67     Algeria 2006           0          0                  0
68     Algeria 2007           0          0                  0
69     Algeria 2008           0          0                  0
70     Algeria 2009           0          0                  0
71     Algeria 2010           0          0                  0
72     Algeria 2011           0          0                  0
73     Algeria 2012           0          0                  0
74     Algeria 2013           0          0                  0
75     Algeria 2014           0          0                  0
76     Algeria 2015           0          0                  0
77     Algeria 2016           0          0                  0
78     Algeria 2017           0          0                  0
79     Algeria 2018           0          0                  0
80     Algeria 2019           0          0                  0
81   Argentina 1980           1          0                  0
82   Argentina 1981           0          1                  0
83   Argentina 1982           0          0                  1
84   Argentina 1983           0          0                  0
85   Argentina 1984           0          0                  0
86   Argentina 1985           0          0                  0
87   Argentina 1986           0          0                  0
88   Argentina 1987           0          1                  0
89   Argentina 1988           0          0                  0
90   Argentina 1989           1          0                  0
91   Argentina 1990           0          0                  0
92   Argentina 1991           0          0                  0
93   Argentina 1992           0          0                  0
94   Argentina 1993           0          0                  0
95   Argentina 1994           0          0                  0
96   Argentina 1995           1          0                  0
97   Argentina 1996           0          0                  0
98   Argentina 1997           0          0                  0
99   Argentina 1998           0          0                  0
100  Argentina 1999           0          0                  0
101  Argentina 2000           0          0                  0
102  Argentina 2001           1          0                  1
103  Argentina 2002           0          1                  0
104  Argentina 2003           0          0                  0
105  Argentina 2004           0          0                  0
106  Argentina 2005           0          0                  0
107  Argentina 2006           0          0                  0
108  Argentina 2007           0          0                  0
109  Argentina 2008           0          0                  0
110  Argentina 2009           0          0                  0
111  Argentina 2010           0          0                  0
112  Argentina 2011           0          0                  0
113  Argentina 2012           0          0                  0
114  Argentina 2013           0          1                  0
115  Argentina 2014           0          0                  1
116  Argentina 2015           0          0                  0
117  Argentina 2016           0          0                  0
118  Argentina 2017           0          0                  0
119  Argentina 2018           0          0                  0
120    Armenia 1980           0          0                  0
121    Armenia 1981           0          0                  0
122    Armenia 1982           0          0                  0
123    Armenia 1983           0          0                  0
124    Armenia 1984           0          0                  0
125    Armenia 1985           0          0                  0
126    Armenia 1986           0          0                  0
127    Armenia 1987           0          0                  0
128    Armenia 1988           0          0                  0
129    Armenia 1989           0          0                  0
130    Armenia 1990           0          0                  0
131    Armenia 1991           0          0                  0
132    Armenia 1992           0          0                  0
133    Armenia 1993           0          0                  0
134    Armenia 1994           1          0                  0
135    Armenia 1995           0          0                  0
136    Armenia 1996           0          0                  0
137    Armenia 1997           0          0                  0
138    Armenia 1998           0          0                  0
139    Armenia 1999           0          0                  0
140    Armenia 2000           0          0                  0
141    Armenia 2001           0          0                  0
142    Armenia 2002           0          0                  0
143    Armenia 2003           0          0                  0
144    Armenia 2004           0          0                  0
145    Armenia 2005           0          0                  0
146    Armenia 2006           0          0                  0
147    Armenia 2007           0          0                  0
148    Armenia 2008           0          0                  0
149    Armenia 2009           0          0                  0
150    Armenia 2010           0          0                  0
151    Armenia 2011           0          0                  0
152    Armenia 2012           0          0                  0
153    Armenia 2013           0          0                  0
154    Armenia 2014           0          0                  0
155    Armenia 2015           0          0                  0
156    Armenia 2016           0          0                  0
157    Armenia 2017           0          0                  0
158    Armenia 2018           0          0                  0
159    Armenia 2019           0          0                  0
160    Austria 1980           0          0                  0
161    Austria 1981           0          0                  0
162    Austria 1982           0          0                  0
163    Austria 1983           0          0                  0
164    Austria 1984           0          0                  0
165    Austria 1985           0          0                  0
166    Austria 1986           0          0                  0
167    Austria 1987           0          0                  0
168    Austria 1988           0          0                  0
169    Austria 1989           0          0                  0
170    Austria 1990           0          0                  0
171    Austria 1991           0          0                  0
172    Austria 1992           0          0                  0
173    Austria 1993           0          0                  0
174    Austria 1994           0          0                  0
175    Austria 1995           0          0                  0
176    Austria 1996           0          0                  0
177    Austria 1997           0          0                  0
178    Austria 1998           0          0                  0
179    Austria 1999           0          0                  0
180    Austria 2000           0          0                  0
181    Austria 2001           0          0                  0
182    Austria 2002           0          0                  0
183    Austria 2003           0          0                  0
184    Austria 2004           0          0                  0
185    Austria 2005           0          0                  0
186    Austria 2006           0          0                  0
187    Austria 2007           0          0                  0
188    Austria 2008           1          0                  0
189    Austria 2009           0          0                  0
190    Austria 2010           0          0                  0
191    Austria 2011           0          0                  0
192    Austria 2012           0          0                  0
193    Austria 2013           0          0                  0
194    Austria 2014           0          0                  0
195    Austria 2015           0          0                  0
196    Austria 2016           0          0                  0
197    Austria 2017           0          0                  0
198    Austria 2018           0          0                  0
199    Austria 2019           0          0                  0
200 Bangladesh 1980           0          0                  0
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Comment: something in here might help: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-area-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Comment: @akash87 does this helps? Thank you !

Comment: @Carlota Olivera to provide data try use the `dput` function (`dput(YOURDATA)`). It will automatically create a structure that can be loaded as an object :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved like so:

1. Instead of summarising each type of crisis separately you can do this in one step. Also it's not necessary to filter. As your crisis variables are coded as 0 and 1 you can simply sum.
2. To simplify the plotting it's best to convert the summarized dataset to long format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

panel_3_sum <- panel_3 %>%   
  group_by(Year)%>%
  summarise(across(c(lv18_bank_c, lv18_cur_c, lv18_sovdebt_c_def), sum)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = "type", values_to = "freq")
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot(panel_3_sum, aes(Year, freq, fill = type)) +
  geom_area()
```

[image]